# MobileNet depthmultiplier parameters

Tags: tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I have a confusing about the `depth-multiplier (alpha)` parameters in `tf.keras.layers.SeparableConv2D` and

`tf.keras.layers.DepthwiseConv2D`

Based on the original paper, M inputs channel will be `alpha*M` where `alpha` in ]0,1]. My question is how to remove the channels? I am guessing it is randomly like dropout ? Thanks to clarify

Answer (score 0):

It's about an output shape. `depth_multiplier` is a number of filters applied to each input channel. This is an integer positive number, so if you have 3 channels and `depth_multiplier == 4`, after depthwise convolution you'll get 12 channels (4 filters for each of 3 channels)

From the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/DepthwiseConv2D):

> The total number of depthwise convolution output channels will be equal to filters_in * depth_multiplier

If you want to apply filters to all channels, but not for each separately, you'll need [a regular convolution](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv2D) instead of depthwise.